# perfs manager in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu

When I was under Ubuntu 14.04, I had in the title bar a menu that allowed me to choosee between *high performances* or *energy saving* for the processor.
I want to know what app it was, I can't remember... Thermald? Conky? Perf? Something else?
And btw can it run under Kubuntu or Lubuntu?